# MA, Sound in New Media; Finland

Tags: masters-degree

Hi there!

I'm wondering if there is anyone out there who enrolled this MA at Aalto University. I will run for it next year and would like to know better from an insider perspective. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hello, I studied/graduated from Aalto University Media Lab in 2004 - 2006 - before the Sound in New Media course or Aalto University existed. My tutor was Antti Ikonen who now runs the Sound in New Media Course, and we still meet up from time to time to discuss audio related matters. I would definitely recommend it. Aalto University is not one university but 4+ different university's and schools in collaboration, (the art school, technical university, economics school etc.) - so as a student you can choose within reason whichever course you feel you need to graduate. For example I was taking Programming courses at the technical university along side my sound/art courses. If you are looking for a basic audio engineering style of course this is not it (go to the SAE instead :)) - but if you have some good ideas, and are pro-active, you'll get a lot of support and help to achieve you goals.

Comment: Hey, @RedSonic1, thank you. I have already graduated in Music Production and Technology so now I'm looking more to learn about actual sound design with professional guidance, because that is what I feel it's lacking right now. 